# Плавный поворот по вектору Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
Vector2 new_rotation = _enemy.transform.position - transform.position;
transform.up = new_rotation;
```

данный код резко поворачивает объект по направлению вектора. А как сделать плавный поворот по вектору?

Comment: Либо используйте корутины, либо в Update используйте множитель Time.deltaTime

Comment: поворачивайте с помощью физики + `Time.deltaTime`

Comment: И ещё, не называл бы ты переменные направления, как rotation. То, что ты называешь rotation, в твоём случае это direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    [SerializeField]
    float _velocity = 10; //скорость поворота

    Transform _target; //Цель, за которой будем следить

    public void SetTarget(Transform target)
    {
        _target = target; //устанавливаем цель, например откуда-то снаружи
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_target != null) //если есть цель - поворачиваемся в её сторону
        {
            Vector2 new_rotation = _target.position - transform.position;
            transform.up = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.up, new_rotation, Time.deltaTime * _velocity); 
        }
    }
```

Метод [Vector2.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html) (и его перегрузки для других значимых типов) сдвигает нас от текущего значения в сторону целевого на значение третьего параметра (maxDistanceDelta), но не дальше, чем до целевого значения. Например:

```
Mathf.MoveToward(0, 1, 0.5f)    //вернёт 0.5f    
Mathf.MoveToward(0.7f, 1, 0.5f) //вернёт 1    
Mathf.MoveToward(0.5f, 0, 0.6f) //вернёт 0
```